# Roll over image of image button onClick of it

Tags: android, image, dynamic, imagebutton

i am trying to change the image of my button as shown below.

```
else if (v == btnUt) {
                Intent toUtilities = new Intent(City.this, UtilityScreen.class);

//btnUt is the name of my image button
                btnUt.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mapicon));

}
```

Here the problem am facing is, it sets tow images for the same button, I want the previous image not to be shown when I reset new one for it.

Note: I do not want to use selectors instead pro-grammatically I am trying to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have set the background drawable of the layout in which the button is located. Make sure that the layout in which the button is located, does not have a background drawable.

Comment: No. I have not declared background drawable for my button

Comment: Hi, it is working fine now, I removed the src tag of the button.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for setting the ImageButton's image:

```
btnUt.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mapicon));
```